# UWP App: Interact with a windows application with something else than a mouse/keyboard?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I'm currently doing a test UWP app, the goal would be to put this on a Raspberry PI with Win 10 IOT ont it.

I've not much content, the application just display all the zodiac signs, and when one signed is clicked, it displays the current sign information. This will be display on a monitor here. So I would like to be able to navigate between sign, with a remote by example(but I'm open to any other proposal).

What would be the more adequate to navigate on the application(knowing that I don't need to enter anything, that it's not a touch screen but a simple monitor).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use the GPIO port on the Raspberry Pi to connect the device with any of external controllers of your choice. Wired buttons would be pretty simple, and for a remote your could use an infrared receiver. The GPIO allows you to interact with pretty much anything electronic so the possibilities are pretty much endless.

For interacting with the GPIO port you need to add a reference to the "Windows IoT Extension SDK" to your universal windows app project.

The [samples repository](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples) has code examples on how to interact with the GPIO port, and many of them are explained [with tutorials](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/startcoding).

Comment: Well, I would prefer to use something more standard, in order to be able to run it on devices that doesn't have GPIO